# Python os.pipe vs multiprocessing.Pipe

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pipe, communication

Recently I'm studying parallel programming tools in Python. And here are two major differences between os.pipe and multiprocessing.Pipe.(despite the occasion they are used)

1. os.pipe is **unidirectional**, multiprocessing.Pipe is **bidirectional**;
2. When putting things into pipe/receive things from pipe, os.pipe uses **encode/decode**, while  multiprocessing.Pipe uses **pickle/unpickle**

I want to know if my understanding is correct, and is there other difference? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe everything you've stated is correct.

On Linux, `os.pipe` is just a Python interface for accessing traditional POSIX pipes. On Windows, it's implemented using `CreatePipe`. When you call it, you get two ordinary file descriptors back. It's unidirectional, and you just write bytes to it on one end that get buffered by the kernel until someone reads from the other side. It's fairly low-level, at least by Python standards.

`multiprocessing.Pipe` objects are much more high level interface, implemented using `multiprocessing.Connection` objects. On Linux, these are actually built on top of POSIX sockets, rather than POSIX pipes. On Windows, they're built using the `CreateNamedPipe` API. As you noted, `multiprocessing.Connection` objects can send/receive any picklable object, and will automatically handle the pickling/unpickling process, rather than just dealing with bytes. They're capable of being both bidirectional and unidirectional.